# Training a neural network with constrained units

Tags: neural-network, biological-neural-network

**Motivation:**

The state of the art algorithm for object recognition is a deep convolutional neural net trained through backpropagation, where the main problem is getting the network to settle in a good local minima: http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips25/NIPS2012_0534.pdf

It is possible to record spike counts from the brain from neurons that support object recognition, and it is reasonable to claim that the neural network that approximates the response of these neurons is in a good local minima. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089662731200092X

If you were to constrain a subset of units in a neural net to reproduce certain values for certain inputs (say for example, the spike counts recorded from neurons in response to these images), and then reduce the error by a constrained gradient descent, it may be able to force the network to settle in a good local minima.

**Precise question:**

What would be the most computationally efficient way to alter the weights of a neural network in the direction that maximizes the reduction in error given that some neurons in the network must have certain pre-determined values?

**Progress thus far:**

This seems to be a very difficult Lagrange multiplier problem, and after doing some work on it and searching for existing literature on the topic, I was wondering if anyone had heard of similar work.

Comment: Maybe you can train the constrained neurons by standard backpropagation to produce the desired values, fix their weights so that they are just a sophisticated feature extractor and then, train only the upper layers by backpropagation for classification. Anyway, that could be an interesting research topic. I'm curious to see your paper about that. :)

Comment: The problem with this is that there is not enough neural data to avoid overfitting in the first step of the procedure you suggest. However, it might be a good idea to _not_ fix the weights, and then alternate between step 1 and step 2.

(STEP 1 = train constrained neurons, STEP 2= train for classification)

It would be great if I could somehow ensure that alternation between these steps will converge to a stable point, but maybe the best way is to simply try it!

Comment: @dardila2 I know this isn't an answer to your question, but gaussian mutation would be able to solve this problem trivially. Do you really need gradient-descent methods?

Comment: Do you have a citation or some other resource to understand what you mean by Gaussian mutation? Often for optimizing large neural networks, gradient descent has empirically shown to be very effective: this is the only reason I wanted to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is Kullback-Liebler Divergence (KL). It allows you to set the value you wish your neurons to be close to. In python it's,

```
def _binary_KL_divergence(p, p_hat):
    """
    Computes the a real, KL divergence of two binomial distributions with
    probabilities p  and p_hat respectively.
    """
    return (p * np.log(p / p_hat)) + ((1 - p) * np.log((1 - p) / (1 - p_hat)))
```

where `p` is the constrained value, and `p_hat` is the average activation value (or neuron value) of your samples. It is as simple as adding the term to the objective function. So, if the algorithm minimizes the square error `||H(X) - y||^2`, the new form would be `||H(X) - y||^2 + KL_divergence_term`.

As part of the cost function, it penalizes the average activations that diverge from `p` whether higher or lower (Figure 1). How the weight updates depends on the partial differentiation of the new objective function.

[image]

```
                     (Figure 1 : KL-Divergence Cost when `p = 0.2)
```

In fact, I burrowed this idea from Sparse Auto-encoders, where more details can be seen at [Lecture Notes on Sparse Autoencoders](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf).

Good luck!

Comment: I like the idea of adding a term to the loss, and this is in fact what I have been experimenting with, so I'll select this as the answer for now. However, why use KL-Divergence rather than square error or some other such simple metric?

Comment: The benefit of KL-Divergence lies in its non-symmetric nature and sparsity control. We can observe from the figure above how values below "p = 0.2" are less penalized than higher values, meaning it encourages sparsity more than if we used simpler regularization terms. Secondly, the value of `p` determines how much sparsity we want. For different data, different sparsity values is desirable.